# Difference Sets

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, recursive-algorithms, extremal-combinatorics

suppose we have a set $$P=\{p_1,p_2,...,p_K\}$$
where $$1\leq p_k\leq N , k=1,...,K \qquad \& \quad p_k \in \mathbb{N} $$ and $p_k$'s are distinct.
We calculate the differences as: $$d=p_i-p_j\mod N,\quad i\ne j$$
Now let $a_d$ denote the number of occurrence of d (d = 1, 2, . . . , N −
1), then we have a set $$A=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_{N-1} \}$$
As you know given $P$ and $N$, it is easy to build $A$; Although given $A$ and $K$ there could be many $P$'s leading to $A$ or even no possible $P$ leading to $A$.
I want to know, given $A$ and $K$, is there any algorithm just saying whether there is a $P$ leading to this $A$ or not ?

Comment: At the very minimum, you need $a_i=a_{N-i}$ and $\sum a_i = K^2-K$.

Comment: You would want an $a_N$ or $a_0$ term too, and Thomas's sum should include this term. This value must be equal to $\frac{l^2-l}{2}$ for some $l$.

Comment: Yes, You are right. but i'm looking for an algorithm.